# Problema con PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Estoy intentando pasar un test con un código y la extensión de PHPUnit para Visual Studio. Sin embargo, el código para el test tiene errores, según PHPUnit, por ejemplo:

-El código indica "use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase". Sin embargo, cuando declaras que la clase principal hereda de TestCase, Visual Studio indica que PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase es un tipo indefinido

Hay más errores, pero creo que son derivados de que el código no hereda TestCase y de ahí que métodos y demás me aparezcan como que no han sido definidos

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Sin el código es dificil saber de qué puede tratarse. ¿Tienes importadas las clases?

```
require_once ('PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php');

//O en su defecto el autoload
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```